# Date field datatype text in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch data between two range but in my database Date field as Text.
How Now fetch data between two range

```
         $startdate = 01-01-2020
         $enddate = 31-12-2020
```

and my database field name DATE as text datatype(format 01-12-2019)
Below is the query I am using

```
            SELECT m.id, m.centers, c.BUDGET_ANNUAL_AMOUNT
            FROM Cost_centers m INNER JOIN ANNUAL_BUDGET_BUDGET_CENTER c 
            ON c.BUDGET_ID = 25
            where (START_DATE BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate')
            ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Please help how to get data with text datattype with range. How to convert text to data .
Please help me

Comment: Use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for your date literals.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using [STR_TO_DATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function available in mysql ?
I think something like below should work.

```
SELECT m.id, m.centers, c.BUDGET_ANNUAL_AMOUNT
            FROM Cost_centers m INNER JOIN ANNUAL_BUDGET_BUDGET_CENTER c 
            ON c.BUDGET_ID = 25
            where (STR_TO_DATE(START_DATE, "%d-%m-%Y") BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate')
            ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Hi, I have double checked the query and it does provide the result you want. Can you try putting `startdate` and `enddate` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Answer (score 0):

According to
[My SQL Reference - DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATE,%3Amm%3Ass%20%27%20format.)

MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

I would suggest trying this format.

There is also a worked example where variables are used in date queries on :

[TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-how-to-declare-a-datetime-variable)